# Two extra views put inside of a ForEach with a filtering search bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui

So I have a ScrollView that contains a list of all the contacts imported from a user's phone. Above the ScrollView, I have a 'filter search bar' that has a binding that causes the list to show only contacts where the name contains the same string as the search bar filter. For some reason, the last two contacts in the list always pop up at the bottom of the list, no matter what the string is (even if it's a string not contained in any of the contact names on the phone). I tried deleting a contact and the problem persists, because the original contact was just replaced with the new second to last contact. Any help fixing this would be much appreciated!

```
            struct SomeView: View {
                @State var friendsFilterText: String = ""
                @State var savedContacts: CustomContact = []
                var body: some View {
                var filteredContactsCount = 0
                if friendsFilterText.count != 0 {
                    for contact in appState.savedContacts {
                        if contact.name.lowercased().contains(friendsFilterText.lowercased()) {
                            filteredContactsCount += 1
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    filteredContactsCount = savedContacts.count
                }
                return HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    ZStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Type a name...")
                                .opacity(friendsFilterText.count > 0 ? 0 : 1)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        CocoaTextField("", text: $friendsFilterText)
                        .background(Color.clear)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        friendsFilterText = ""
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                    })
                }.frame(height: 38)
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Your contacts (\(filteredContactsCount))")
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    fetchContacts()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    // edit button action
                }, label: {
                    Text("Edit")
                })
                
                
            }
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(savedContacts, id: \.self.name) { contact in
                    if contact.name.lowercased().contains(friendsFilterText.lowercased()) || friendsFilterText.count == 0 {
                        Button(action: {
                            // contact button action
                        }, label: {
                            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                               Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                                    .font(.system(size: 41))
                                    .frame(width: 41, height: 41)
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                    Text(contact.name)
                                    Text(contact.phoneNumber)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }.frame(height: 67)
                        })
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

CustomContact is a custom struct with properties phoneNumber and name. I've attached images below of the issue I'm experiencing. I'm thinking MAYBE it's because there's something off timing-wise with the friendsFilterText and the ForEach rendering but I'm really not sure.

In the image set below, the 'Extra Contact 1' and 'Extra Contact 2' are ALWAYS rendered, unless I add a filter, then switch to a different view, then back to this view (which leads me to believe it's a timing thing again).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpVpp.jpg

Comment: could you show the code of a minimum reproducible example. The code you show is not a valid View,
 it does not have a "body", or contains code that should not be inside a view's body.

Comment: @workingdog Updated, I felt like for simplicity sake I'd just keep the stacks and 'functional' code that's used. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You should move the count calculation out of the view into a computed var.

And if CustomContact is your single contact struct, it should actually read `@State var savedContacts: [CustomContact] = []` i.e. an array of CustomContact.

The rest worked fine with me, no extra contacts showing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var friendsFilterText: String = ""
    @State var savedContacts: [CustomContact] = []
    
    // computed var
    var filteredContactsCount: Int {
        if friendsFilterText.isEmpty { return savedContacts.count }
        return savedContacts.filter({ $0.name.lowercased().contains(friendsFilterText.lowercased()) }).count
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
...
```

[image]